# How can I match the parenthesis and number inside it through regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to match the number decimal place and parenthesis which may or may not there .
For example different pattern may be :

```
233.44
264.00
23456.345
(2678.200)
```

I want the out put as its without removing the optional parenthesis. I wrote regex which checks only number and decimal place but not the brackets .My regex is below

```
\d+(\.\d{1,2})?
```

Any clue how to include the parenthesis will help here.I want to do this in java

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question, and want to add `(` and `)` as optional in your pattern. Something like,

```
String re = "\\(*\\d+(\\.\\d+)?\\)*";
String[] arr = { "233.44", "264.00", "23456.345", "(2678.200)" };
for (String s : arr) {
    System.out.println(s.matches(re));
}
```

Which outputs

```
true
true
true
true
```

Comment: I tested this pattern in javaregex online complier I see Dangling meta charcter

Comment: This is where I tested https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html#ad-output

Comment: @Rajesh When written in a Java `String` literal, you have to write ``\`` as ``\\``. Use `\(*\d+(\.\d+)?\)*` in your regex-tester for the same regular expression.

Comment: Thanks @Elliott It works .Now I changed my regex to handle comma too with your help \(*(?:\d+)((\d)*([\,\ ]\d)*)(\.\d+)?\)*

Comment: You seem to have dropped a ``\`` before `(` and a `*` after it. `\(*\d+(\.\d{1,2})?\)*` should work. But, glad I could help.